# Wordpress page complete text gets underlined when page is hovered

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a website for myself in WordPress using Elementor free plugin and Phlox theme. I've just started and completed a couple of sections. Each section has some text, buttons and some images. The issue I'm facing here right now is that when I open the website and move my mouse pointer inside the Webpage area, the text in all sections gets underlined just like any hyperlink but there is no hyperlink with any text. I've checked settings in customizations and other stuff in theme settings but nothing helped. I'm new on WordPress and don't know how to debug this in any technical depth. Please have a look and tell me how can I fix this issue.

I can't continue with these underlined text appearing all over my page.

Link : [myWebPage](http://dubaitruckrental.com/)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.csstransitions .aux-page-show-circle.aux-page-animation-done #inner-body, .csstransitions .aux-page-show-circle.aux-page-animation-done {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: the lines are gone now but when i click on any menu item and page is changed/reloaded i can see the underlines again for a second or two. any ideas?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the page loading animations. I disabled page loading animation and now it was back to underlines again.

Answer (score 0):

Always attempt to use your browser dev tools to check these things. In your css you have this in your custom.css file. Dont know why its there but thats the cause

```
body:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: yeah, i knew it was something with the decoration but couldn't find anything in Inspect Element, i'm just a beginner i guess. so i thought may be its the theme issue. but thanks for your kind support.

Comment: I tried your CSS code with text-decoration: none; and it worked.